# FriendlyID does not find entry with matching slug

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, friendly-id

FriendlyID does not seem to find a database entry with the corresponding slug.

Here is what the console shows:

> Started GET "/budgets/drinks" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-07-01 12:42:53
>   +0200 Processing by BudgetsController#show as HTML   Parameters: {"id"=>"drinks"}   Budget Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "budgets".* FROM
>   "budgets"  WHERE "budgets"."slug" = 'drinks'  ORDER BY "budgets"."id"
>   ASC LIMIT 1   User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE
>   "users"."id" = 1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1   MoneyTransaction
>   Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "money_transactions".* FROM "money_transactions" 
>   WHERE "money_transactions"."budget_id" = ?  [["budget_id", 17]]
>   Budget Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "budgets".* FROM "budgets"  WHERE
>   "budgets"."user_id" = ?  [["user_id", 1]]   Rendered
>   budgets/_budget_overview.html.erb (5.5ms)   Rendered
>   budgets/_form.html.erb (7.0ms)   Rendered budgets/show.html.erb within
>   layouts/application (26.3ms) Completed 200 OK in 224ms (Views: 213.5ms
>   | ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)
>
> Started POST "/money_transactions" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-07-01
>   12:43:06 +0200 Processing by MoneyTransactionsController#create as
>   HTML   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",
>   "authenticity_token"=>"EPcX4adigoTRY6A1doxWpdMM9eXy/KyqY84zKp855bE=",
>   "money_transaction"=>{"budget_id"=>"drinks", "amount"=>"24",
>   "title"=>"coke"}, "button"=>""}   User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".*
>   FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT
>   1   Budget Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "budgets".* FROM "budgets"  WHERE
>   "budgets"."slug" = 'drinks'  ORDER BY "budgets"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
>   (0.1ms)  begin transaction   Budget Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "budgets".*
>   FROM "budgets"  WHERE "budgets"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 0]]
>   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction    (0.0ms)  begin transaction    (0.1ms)
>   rollback transaction Redirected to
>   http://localhost:3000/budgets/drinks Completed 302 Found in 14ms
>   (ActiveRecord: 0.7ms)

This shows that the slug exists and is correctly related to the ID when I access the page. However after looking for for an entry with the slug "drinks" it only returns an ID of 0.

> Budget Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "budgets".* FROM "budgets"  WHERE
>   "budgets"."slug" = 'drinks'  ORDER BY "budgets"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
>   (0.1ms)  begin transaction   Budget Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "budgets".*
>   FROM "budgets"  WHERE "budgets"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 0]]

**money_transaction_controller.rb**

```
def create
    @budget = Budget.friendly.find(params[:money_transaction][:budget_id])
    @money_transaction = MoneyTransaction.new(money_transaction_params)
    @money_transaction.user = current_user
    @money_transaction.date = Time.now.to_date
    @money_transaction.is_positive = 0

    @money_transaction.save

    respond_to do |format|
      if @money_transaction.save
        format.html { redirect_to @budget, notice: 'Transaction added.'}
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @budget }
      else
        format.html { redirect_to @budget, alert: 'Transaction was not valid.'}
        format.json { render json: @money_transaction.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

**budget.rb**

```
class Budget < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :money_transactions

  validates :amount, presence: true
  validates :title, presence: true
  validates :user, presence: true
  validates :amount, numericality: true

  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :title, use: :slugged

  def should_generate_new_friendly_id?
    new_record?
  end
end
```

**budgets/show.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(@budget.money_transactions.build, :html => { :id => 'money_transaction-form' }) do |f| %>
      <%= f.hidden_field :budget_id, :value => params[:id] %>

      <%= f.number_field :amount, id: "transaction-input", placeholder: "#{@budget.title} ", step: 0.01, :autocomplete => :off %>

      <%= f.text_field :title, class: "", placeholder: "purpose", :autocomplete => :off %>

      <%= f.button(type: 'submit', class: "postfix") do %>
          <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i>
      <% end %>

<% end %>
```

**routes.rb**

```
  get '/pages', to: 'pages#index'

  devise_for :users
  resources :users

  resources :budget
  resources :money_transactions


  root :to => 'budgets#index'
```

Let me know if you need any other files. I worked with friendlyID before and never had problems. I hope you can help me.

**EDIT:** 
So I found a workaround. But I feel like there should be a simpler solution. I changed my hidden field to:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :budget_id, :value => Budget.where(:slug => params[:id]).last.id %>
```

Now it works. But if you have a better solution, please let me know.

Comment: Do you have an attributes called slug into your corresponding model which is currently using the friendly-id extension then please try the query in the rails console, may help you to get solved the issues.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. I did check in the Rails console and I can find the model with it's slug:

> Budget.where(:slug => "drinks")

  Budget Load (4.0ms)  SELECT "budgets".* FROM "budgets"  WHERE "budgets"."slug" = 'drinks'
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Budget id: 17, title: "Drinks", amount: #<BigDecimal:7f904bb14eb8,'0.3478E4',9(27)>, refresh_rate: nil, created_at: "2015-06-30 12:22:34", updated_at: "2015-06-30 12:22:34", user_id: 1, slug: "drinks">]>

Comment: parameters should comes in slug not in id.

Comment: Try to update your routes brother.

Comment: Sorry, what exactly do you mean? Which route should I update?

Comment: Share your routes file here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use FriendlyID for form parameters - just use the straight ID. That lets rails automatically add the association and results in a much more effective SQL query.

```
<%= form_for(@budget.money_transactions.build, :html => { :id => 'money_transaction-form' }) do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :budget_id, value: @budget.id %>
  <%= f.number_field :amount, id: "transaction-input", placeholder: "#{@budget.title} ", step: 0.01, :autocomplete => :off %>
  <%= f.text_field :title, class: "", placeholder: "purpose", :autocomplete => :off %>
  <%= f.button(type: 'submit', class: "postfix") do %>
    <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

With that you can clean up your controller:

```
def create
  @money_transaction = MoneyTransaction.new(money_transaction_params) do |mt|
    mt.user = current_user
    mt.date = Time.now.to_date
    mt.is_positive = 0
  end
  respond_to do |format|
    if @money_transaction.save
      format.html { redirect_to @budget, notice: 'Transaction added.'}
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @budget }
    else
      format.html { redirect_to @budget, alert: 'Transaction was not valid.'}
      format.json { render json: @money_transaction.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: That looks much nicer and simpler than my silly workaround. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I just saw that you were creating the form from the budget#show method. Removed the #new action from my answer.